# Mysqli rollback not working

Tags: php, transactions, mysqli, rollback, autocommit

The Mysqli documentation indicates that if the call `autocommit(false)` returns true, it was successful in disabling the automatic committing of queries. 
Still, if I try to rollback the transaction, created like the following code, the information remains deleted.

```
$dbConn= new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die('Could not connect');
$dbConn->autcocommit(false); //returns true
$dbConn->query($deleteQuery);
$dbConn->query($deleteQuery2);
$dbConn->rollback();
```

What could go wrong in this situation?

Comment: Does your table [storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) support transactions?

Comment: I've looked it up and the tables are configured MyIsam, so apparently not. But would the return of the autocommit function of MySqli not indicate this problem?

Comment: You are setting autocommit on the connection, not on the specific table, so basically function cannot indicate this problem. All that this function does is run a query like `SET autocommit = {0 | 1}`.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback only works with InnoDB tables not MyISAM. Make sure the tables you are using in $deleteQuery (query) is InnoDB.