# PHP mysqli->rollback() not working after deleting table data

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions

My database uses the **InnoDB** engine, but it seems I am unable to rollback a transaction.

Here is my code:

```
try {

    $transaction_started = $mysqli->autocommit( FALSE ); // begin transaction
    if ($transaction_started === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception( "Could not start transaction." );
    }

    $mysqli->query( "DELETE FROM `my_table`" ); // empty table

    $mysqli->query( "ALTER TABLE `my_table` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;" ); // reset auto-increment value

    throw new Exception( "Test" );

    $mysqli->commit();

}
catch (Exception $e) {

    $transaction_rolled_back = $mysqli->rollback(); // rollback the transaction.
    if ($transaction_rolled_back === FALSE) {
        echo "Rollback failed!";
    }

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

When I run this code, the exception is caught and no "Rollback failed!" message is shown - which suggests the rollback has worked. But the data in my table gets deleted.

Is rollback not supposed to work for deleted data or is there something I have done wrong or something I may not have checked?

I've seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972279/mysqli-rollback-is-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219368/mysqli-rollback-not-working), but they don't solve my problem.

Comment: Most if not all DDL command like `ALTER TABLE` have an Implied COMMIT in them. So that will be committing your detete

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957232/can-i-undo-alter-table-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks to the input from @RiggsFolly, my solution was to save the AUTO_INCREMENT value from the table in a `$saved_auto_inc_value` variable, then set the AUTO_INCREMENT value in the table to 1, and **then** do all the transaction stuff. If an exception was caught, then rollback and set AUTO_INCREMENT in the table to `$saved_auto_inc_value` which leaves everything back as it was.